# what is the pythonic way to test dataframe processing pipelines

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

What is the best way to go about testing a pandas dataframe processing chain?  I stubbed out the script file and the test file below so you can see what I mean.

I am getting confused on best practice, my only guiding intuition is to make the tests so they can run in any order, limit how many times the csv is loaded from disk, while also making sure each point in the chain does not modify the fixture.  Each step in the process is dependent on the previous steps so unit testing each node is like testing the accumulation of processing to that point in the pipeline.  So far I am accomplishing the mission but it seems like a lot of code duplication is happening because I am incrementally building the pipeline in each test.

What is the way to test this kind of python script?

This is the data processing file stubbed out:

```py
#main_script.py

def calc_allocation_methodology(df_row):
    print('calculating allocation methodoloyg')
    return 'simple'

def flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology(df):       
    allocation_methodology = df.apply(calc_allocation_methodology, axis=1)
    df.assign(allocation_methodology=allocation_methodology)
    print('flagging each row for the allocation methodoloyg')
    return df

def convert_repeating_values_to_nan(df):
    'keep one value and nan the rest of the values'
    print('convert repeating values to nan')
    return df

def melt_and_drop_accounting_columns(df):
    print('melt and drop accounting columns')
    print(f'colums remaining: {df.shape[0]}')
    return df
    
def melt_and_drop_engineering_columns(df):
    print('melt and drop engineering columns')
    print(f'colums remaining: {df.shape[0]}')
    return df
    
    
def process_csv_to_tiny_format(df):
    print('process the entire pipeline')
    return (df
        .pipe(flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology)
        .pipe(convert_repeating_values_to_nan)
        .pipe(melt_and_drop_accounting_columns)
        .pipe(melt_and_drop_engineering_columns)
        )
```

This is the test file stubbed out

```py
#test_main.py


from pytest import fixture
import main_script as main
import pandas as pd

@fixture(scope='session')
def df_from_csv()
    return pd.load_csv('database_dump.csv')

@fixture
def df_copy(df_from_csv):
    df = df_from_csv.copy()
    return df

    
    
def test_expected_flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology(df_copy)
    df = df_copy
    node_to_test = df.pipe(main.flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology)
    assert True

def test_convert_repeating_values_to_nan(df_copy)
    df = df_copy
    node_to_test = df.pipe(main.flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology).pipe(main.convert_repeating_values_to_nan)
    assert True     
        
def test_melt_and_drop_accounting_columns(df_copy)
    df = df_copy
    node_to_test = (df
        .pipe(main.flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology)
        .pipe(main.convert_repeating_values_to_nan)
        .pipe(main.melt_and_drop_accounting_columns))
    assert True         
    
def test_melt_and_drop_engineering_columns(df_copy)
    df = df_copy
    node_to_test = (df
        .pipe(main.flag_data_for_the_allocation_methodology)
        .pipe(main.convert_repeating_values_to_nan)
        .pipe(main.melt_and_drop_accounting_columns)
        .pipe(main.melt_and_drop_engineering_columns))
    assert True     

def test_process_csv_to_tiny_format(df_from_csv):
    df = df_from_csv.copy()
    tiny_data = main.process_csv_to_tiny_format(df)
    assert True
```

Comment: IMO, unit tests are separate from the data you really use. They should be run on small, pre-defined, and unchanging data that ideally capture every possible edge case. You run your functions on these specific inputs and check that all of the outputs are correct. If it passes on this small test set then it gives confidence that your function will properly handle the new data you process through your pipeline. `pandas` has a whole set of [tests](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.5/pandas/tests/groupby/test_apply.py) in their library. You can see they make the input data manually

Comment: assume the unit tests are separate from the data and I am only testing on a small, pre-defined, unchanging dataset that captures all possible use cases.  Would you then agree the test stubs are layed out properly?  Or is it a code smell to copy the pipe code from one test to another only adding a new pipe at the end.

Comment: So my point was that you don't need all of those pipes because, for instance, when you test `melt_and_drop_engineering_columns` you shouldn't be sending your `df` through all of those other processes, or using an output that is depending on running those in the first place. Basically `melt_and_drop_engineering_columns` should be able to be run independently without reference to anything else. You might think this is odd because perhaps `melt_and_drop_engineering_columns` requires some very specific output from a previous function. But again, you'd have a unit test for that previous function

Comment: And so that unit test for the previous function (i.e. `melt_and_drop_accounting_columns`) should ensure that your output is exactly in the form it needs to be for the next function

Comment: ok so it sounds like I really only need a helper function that loads the expected df from a flat file and then do comparisons between the expected df and the result df

Comment: do you think it is important to see the data in python or is it trouble to keep the input and expected output in a flat file?